# How to install ssl certificates signed by CA into tomcat 8

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, tomcat

I have 2 certificates signed by CA. I want to enable ssl on tomcat using these certificates.

I ran the following commands to create jks file and imported the certificates into that jks file.

```
1. keytool -genkey -alias bmark.com -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks
2. keytool -import -alias root -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file b32dasd75493.crt
3. keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

And enabled https in server.xml of tomcat

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/Users/test/Desktop/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeme"/>
```

Started tomcat and opened url https://bmark.com:8080 in chrome but it claims that CA-signed SSL certificate is not trusted, claims it is self-signed. Do I need any other files apart from these?
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: On [your previous Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895937/how-to-install-ssl-certificates-signed-by-ca-into-tomcat-8) I told you THREE things: (1) you must import the server cert from the CA -- which `b32dasd75493.crt` almost certainly is -- _to the privatekey entry_ which is definitely `-alias bmark.com` (2) 'bundle' is usually multiple certs -- if so you may need to break them apart and import them _separately_ (3) you need to connect using the public name. You've only fixed (3), not (1) and (2). Your failure to do (1) is the reason tomcat uses and browser gets a selfsigned cert.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085. For (2), I have 2 certificates in the bundle.crt. I installed them separately one by one(one as root.crt and other as intermediate.crt) using the commands below: 1. keytool -import -alias root -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file root.crt
2. keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file intermediate.crt. For (1) I used the command : keytool -import -alias bmark.com -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file b32dasd75493.crt. But still the same error. Let me know what Iam missing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error (self-signed) and not a different security error? Look at the entry as Piotr says, and/or with the server running do `keytool -printcert -v -sslserver $host[:$port]` (this shows exactly what it is serving. Did the bundle tell you which cert is what? If not, look at each with `keytool -printcert -file $file` and make sure of the subject and issuer.

Comment: PS: is this an internal system or resolution? On the internet I get bmark.com -> 70.60.131.72 and that system gives me a cert for `{,www.}antiquearts.com` issued Dec 2 by letsencrypt, plus the correct letsencrypt intermediate and no root (which is permitted, but not usual for Java) and it identifies as Apache2.4.6 on CentOS not Tomcat.

Comment: Its internal system under our company network. The error now I am getting is NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. Did you see the commands that i used to import, does they seem right for wild card certificate. Do I need to change anything in the hosts file to match wildcard certificate.

Comment: If you can't check the validity of your certificate yourself, you should add it to the question. Of course we all assume that between your step `1.` in the question (`keytool -genkeypair ...`) and the import of the certificates you generated a CSR (`keytool -certreq`) and got it signed by the CA.

Comment: The commands in your nearly unreadable comment (but not the Q) look right, especially if as Piotr noted keytool did NOT complain about 'unable to establish chain'. The fact the cert is wildcard has no effect at all on keystore management, or on DNS or hosts file which only handle the specific domain(s) actually used NOT the wildcard. You may need to change them for _that_. ...

Comment: ... 'CA invalid' means the browser IS receiving the cert chain (which means your keystore is at least mostly right), but does NOT agree the root CA used is trusted -- this may be a mistake in or by the CA you used, or the browser(s), or both. Since you (now) have root.crt conveniently in a separate file, `keytool -printcert -file root.crt` and _look at it_ to determine whether that CA is one that should be trusted by a particular browser.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the CA response got correctly installed run:

```
keytool -list -keystore /Users/test/Desktop/keystore.jks -alias bmark.com -v
```

It should show you your certificate chain from leaf to root.

In your connector definition you didn't specify the **key alias**, so the first certificate found is used. Change it to:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/Users/test/Desktop/keystore.jks"
           keystorePass="changeme"
           keyAlias="bmark.com" />
```

or, if you are using **Tomcat 8.5** (you shouldn't [use Tomcat 8.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html)), switch to the new SSL configuration:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLS">
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/Users/test/Desktop/keystore.jks"
                     certificateKeystorePassword="changeme"
                     certificateKeyAlias="bmark.com" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

**Edit**: To install all three certificates you just need a file with your certificate and the intermediates in order from stem to root and run:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore /Users/test/Desktop/keystore.jks\
-alias bmark.com -file <chain_file> -trustcacerts
```

or you might insert separately from root to stem.

Comment: Thanks. This worked but in the browser it is showing as NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. I will work on this update this comment if I'm able to resolve it.

Comment: Did the first command give you the whole certificate chain up to you **CA**'s self-signed certificate? You can also use [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) to see the certification chain visually.

Comment: Is there any particular order we need to follow while installing certificates? when I run first command it is certificate chain lengh as 1 even though I installed 3 certificates.

Comment: **keytool** will fail if it does not find the intermediate certificates, so you need to install them from root to stem or all together.

Comment: Actually it is wildcard certificate just got to know. Do I need to use *.bmark.com as alias name and do I need to change anything in hosts file?

Comment: The alias name has no importance. You just have to add the same in the `<Connector>`.

Comment: From the description there _should_ be only one privatekey entry in OP's keystore in which case the alias _shouldn't_ be needed, but it is good practice and if it helps even better.